# How to get last updated value of the same record for each day, week, month and year in Laravel eloquent?

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.6

This is my product_price table:
[image: product price table]
Notice that product_id 1 is updated multiple times on the same day.
This is my current query:

```
$product = ProductPriceModel::where(['product_id' => $request->product_id])->distinct()->latest()->get()->groupBy(function ($date) {
                    return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('Y-m-d');
                });
```

which give me this result:

```
"data": {
    "productDetails": {
        "2018-09-17": [
            {
                "min_price": 0,
                "max_price": 1150,
                "price_diff": "425"
            },
            {
                "min_price": 100,
                "max_price": 200,
                "price_diff": "-945"
            }
        ],
        "2018-09-10": [
            {
                "min_price": 1070,
                "max_price": 1120,
                "price_diff": "-30"
            },
            {
                "min_price": 1100,
                "max_price": 1150,
                "price_diff": "15"
            },
            {
                "min_price": 1080,
                "max_price": 1140,
                "price_diff": "0"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I expect it to return is only one record for each date.
What changes needs to be done in above query to get exactly one record for each date?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get only one record you need to use `first()` in place of `get()` please give a try

```
$product = ProductPriceModel::where(['product_id' => $request->product_id])->distinct()->latest()->first()->groupBy(function ($date) {
                    return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('Y-m-d');
                });
```